# Jquery form validation plugin - how to do something on submit if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple form with a few fields and a couple of checkboxes. What I need is when the `postto` checkbox is checked, it calls a function before it submits.

How can am I able to do this??

```
$("#form").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorContainer: $(".warning"),
    rules: {
        comment: {
            maxlength: 25
        },
        'phone': {
            number: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();  
     }
});


<form id="form" method="post">
    <div class="first"><textarea name="comment" id="comment" tabindex="1" placeholder="Write your fondest memory here *" required></textarea></div>
    <div><label for="firstname">First Name *</label><input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" tabindex="2" required></div>
    <div><label for="lastname">Last Name *</label><input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" tabindex="3" required></div>
    <div><label for="email">Email Address *</label><input name="email" type="email" id="email" tabindex="4" required></div>
    <div><label for="phone">Phone Number *</label><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" tabindex="5" required></div>

    <section>
        <div class="postto"><input name="postto" type="checkbox" id="postto" value="1" tabindex="6"><label for="postto">Post to my wall</label></div>
        <div class="newsletter"><input name="newsletter" type="checkbox" id="newsletter" value="1" tabindex="7"><label for="newsletter">I want to sign up to the Penguin newsletter</label></div>

        <div class="submit-button"><input name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="enter" tabindex="8"></div>   
        <p class="warning">^ Please fill in the required fields with the correct information.</p>
    </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the handler you wish to fire on the `form.submit()`. It will be executed before the form is actually submitted to the webserver.

See: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

`.submit()` is an event just like click, hover, etc. You can bind handlers to it that will be executed before the default action.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code i think you should call your function just before the

```
form.submit()
```

call inside submitHandler, so it should become

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    //your call goes here...
    form.submit();  
 }
```

Comment: I would prefer adding the code to the submit event. That way, you form is submitted in ny other way, it will still execute the extra code.